# Vector questions involving lines and planes.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Two lines are given:

**1)** $$\frac{x-2}{3} = \frac{y+1}{1} = -\frac{z}{4}$$
**2)** $x = t$, $y = 2$ $z = t +1$ So I guess I have to change the first one, based on this?

1) Do the lines cross, or not?

2) Find the angle, between first line, and plane $2x + y − z − 4 = 0$

3) Find the equation of plane, in which there is the first line and the point $A(1;-1;2)$

I tried, but I even forgot how to do the first one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Mantas Please define what you mean by segments? I've taken care of the $LaTeX$ this time but [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/15077#15077) is the best place to learn for yourself

Comment: Try to recall your homework attempts before you ask others to do them for you.

Comment: Thank, I am still new to it. uniquesolution, I couldn't attend school for a month, I am trying my best to learn it. I would never post unless I am really unsure how to do it. @BLAZE i meant lines. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by converting the $2$ lines into vector equations: $$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y  \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+\mu\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 1  \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y  \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

$\color{red}{1.}$ If the two lines cross then there is a value of $\mu$ and $t$ that will satisfy both line equations. You can find this by equating the two lines such that 
$$\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}+\mu\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 1  \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

This implies $$ 2+3\mu=t\tag{a}$$
$$ \mu-1=2\implies \mu =3\tag{b}$$
substitute $(b)$ into $(a)$ $\implies t=11$

For the $z$-component $$-4\mu=t+1$$

With  $\mu =3 \implies -4 \times 3=-12=$ LHS of $z$-component equation.

With  $t =11 \implies 11+1 =12=$ RHS of $z$-component equation

so $-12\ne 12$

Since LHS $\ne$ RHS we conclude that the lines do not intersect (cross) at any point.

$\color{lime}{2.}$ To find the angle between the line and the plane you must first find the angle between the normal and the line, start by converting the plane into vector form
$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y  \\ z \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1  \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}=4$$

the normal is given by $\vec A=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1  \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ and the direction vector of the first line is $\vec B=\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 1  \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}$

Now the angle between the normal vector of the plane and line direction vector is given by the dot product

$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\cfrac{\vec A \cdot \vec B}{\mid \vec A\mid\mid \vec B\mid}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\cfrac{\begin{bmatrix}2 \\1 \\-1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}3 \\1 \\-4 \end{bmatrix}}{\sqrt{(2)^2+(1)^2+(-1)^2} \sqrt{(3)^2+(1)^2+(-4)^2}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\cfrac{6+1+4}{\sqrt{6} \sqrt{26}}\right)=\cos^{-1}\left(\cfrac{11}{\sqrt{6} \sqrt{26}}\right)\approx 28.3^{\circ}$

Subtract this angle from $90^{\circ}$ to get the angle between the line and the plane.

So angle between line and plane is $90^{\circ}-28.3^{\circ}=\color{blue}{61.7^{\circ}}$.

$\color{#F80}{3.}$ To find the equation of the plane containing the **first** line, you need a position vector of a point that lies on that line which is $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and the direction vector of the line itself which is $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 1  \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}$

Now compute the cross-product of these two vectors to get the normal $\vec{n}$ to the plane:

$\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 1  \\ -4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}i & j & k \\2 & -1 & 0 \\3 & 1 & -4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 8  \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}=\vec{n}$

Now use the general vector equation of the plane:$$\vec{r}\cdot\vec{n}=\vec{a}\cdot\vec{n}$$ where $\vec{r}$ is the position vector relative to the origin of any point $(x,y,z)$ in the plane and $\vec{a}$ is

a known point that lies on the plane. Taking $\vec{a}$ to be $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, the equation of the plane becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y  \\ z \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 8  \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 8  \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}=2\times 4-1\times 8+0\times 5=0$$

In Cartesian coordinates the equation of the plane is 
$$\color{blue}{4x+8y+5z=0}$$

To find the equation of the plane containing the **second** line, you need a position vector of a point

that lies on that line which is $\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and the direction vector of the line itself which is $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now computing the cross-product of these: $\vec{n}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}i & j & k \\0 & 2 & 1 \\1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1  \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$

Now substituting $\vec a =\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\vec n =\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1  \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}$ into the equation of the plane gives

$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y  \\ z \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1  \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 2  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1  \\ -2 \end{bmatrix}=0\times 2+2\times 1+1\times -2=0$$

In Cartesian coordinates the equation of the plane is 
$$\color{blue}{2x+y-2z=0}$$

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't the 2, -1, 4 matrix be 2; -1; 0? And the following one 3; 1; -4?

Comment: @Mantas Yes it should, well spotted! My apologies.

Comment: if you add example 3, could you show how it's done, if it's not the first line and the point, but second + point? I have to sleep, 5AM. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mantas Please see my answer, I've done everything you asked and I'm very tired now myself as this has taken more than 3 hours with all the formatting. I hope my answer will help you. Now I'm off to bed as shattered.

Answer (score 1):

*First question:*

It is simpler to mix Cartesian equation  and parametric representation (as they are): from the parametric representation of the second line, you know the lines intersect if an only if:
$$\frac{t-2}3=3=-\frac{t+1}4,$$
whence $t=11$ from the first equation, $t=-13$  from the second. So there is no intersection point.

*Third question:*

A plane passing through the first line belongs to the pencil of planes defined by the Cartesian equations of the line: this line is the intersection of the planes:
$$x-3y-5=0\quad\text{and}\quad4y+z+4 =0,$$
so a plane of the pencil they define has equation:
$$\lambda(x-3y-5)+\mu(4y+z+4)=0\qquad\text{for some}\enspace\lambda,\mu\in\mathbf {R}.$$
It passes through the point $(1,-1,2)$ if 
$$-\lambda+2\mu=0$$
We'll choose $\mu=1$, whence $\lambda=2$, so an equation of the plane through the first line and the point $(1,-1,2)$ is
$$2x-2y+z-6=0.$$

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did at first, but I wasn't sure it's enough.

Comment: How would it be, if third question had second, instead of first line mentioned? s(z-t-1) + k(x-t) = 0? then change t with x, y and z? s(z-x-1) + k(x-1-y) = 0 -> s(z-x-1) + k(x-3) = 0; Well, it's obviously wrong...

Comment: @Blaze:  thanks for correcting the typos. I just wanted to mention  that I purposely always use oldstyle  boldface for number sets (blackboard bold, as its name indicates, originated in the quasi- impossibility to have boldface with a piece of chalk, ans should be restricted  to blackboard, in my opinion).

Comment: @Bernard Okay, sorry about that Bernard